# Remove Unicode characters from List in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, unicode, ascii

I'm sending information from the Neo-6M GPS module into a Flutter app. So far I've succeeded in getting it in hexadecimal form but converting from the `uint8 List` from the `flutter_blue_serial` library to text, using the convert [library](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/convert/convert-library.html), gives an error. The data is correct, I've manually matched the hexadecimal values against an ASCII table.

The error is that it's trying to convert an invalid character U+005b '[' at offset 0.

```
import 'package:convert/convert.dart';

var con = schedule.bluetoothInstance;
con.input.listen((gpsData){
  var result = hex.decode(gpsData.toString());
  print(result);
});
```

I've changed all the hex values to ASCII 1 to avoid giving away my location but this is what the input data from the HC-05 looks like.

```
I/flutter ( 9322): [45]
I/flutter ( 9322): [49, 49, 46, 49, 49, 49, 49, 49, 49, 49]
I/flutter ( 9322): [49, 49, 49, 49, 49, 49, 49, 49, 49, 49]
I/flutter ( 9322): [49, 49, 49, 49, 49, 13, 10]
```

Is there anyway I can remove all instances of '[' and ']' so I can convert the values to ASCII characters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it using Dart's built in convert library

```
import 'dart:convert';
var con = schedule.bluetoothInstance;
con.input.listen((gpsData){
  print(ascii.decode(gpsData));
});
```